# custom keyboard push layout

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard

I have created a custom keyboard (using KeyboardView) to be used only inside my app.
I add the KeyboardView to my layout but the keyboard just overlays the layout.
I want to push my layout up and add my keyboard at the bottom.
Like [this](http://postimg.org/image/5pbdfrftl/)

I used [this](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm) to create the keyboard.

How is this possible?
I have search the web but didn't find anything...

Setting the windowSoftInputMode doesn't change anything...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding wrapper relative layout that had the keyboard and the view.
And a little playing with the scroll view got it to work.

Comment: Almost 2 years later, I met the same issue . Could you still find your code to provide an example ?  I tried to do this but my set up <RelativeLayout> <ScrollView/><KeyboardView/> </RelativeLayout> did not work because the scrollview is entirely displayed behind the keyboard (it does not scroll as much as I want since it considers that it can use the space behind the keyboard).