# How to push up view when custom keyboard is open from bottom

Tags: android, custom-keyboard

I created a Custom Keyboard in my application using Keyboard tag. I am adding this keyboard in a `RelativeLayout` on my screen like.

```
Keyboard customKeyboard = new Keyboard(getActivity(), R.layout.keyboard);
CustomKeyboard mCustomKeyboard = new CustomKeyboard(getActivity(), this);
mCustomKeyboard.setKeyboard(customKeyboard);
RelativeLayout relLayKeyboard.addView(mCustomKeyboard);
```

Initially I set `android:visibility="invisible"` for *relLayKeyboard*, once I touch on `EditText` I am setting *visibility* to `View.VISIBLE`.

This keyboard I working fine but if there is more `EditText` on the screen then It is coming on the top of that `EditText`. I want to push up the view once *CustomKeyboard* is open on my screen.

Comment: I found two links but not able to get my answer
1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23672433/push-view-above-when-using-custom-keyboard
2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792227/custom-keyboard-push-layout